# Power BI - show data per month

Tags: powerbi

I have two columns I'm trying to display. The first one is `Close date` and the other one is `Open data`. I need to count closed per month and opened per month and put them into a stacked chart. The issue is that close / open month are not the same.

To explain it better, I have included a quick extract:

```
    CLOSE_DTTM  OPEN_DT
01/08/2018  24/05/2018
01/08/2018  31/05/2018
02/08/2018  12/07/2018
02/08/2018  12/07/2018
01/08/2018  26/07/2018
02/08/2018  28/07/2018
02/08/2018  29/07/2018
02/08/2018  31/07/2018
02/08/2018  31/07/2018
02/08/2018  01/08/2018
```

What should I use for the axis in a stack graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a calendar table.

```
Dates = CALENDARAUTO()
```

Use the `Dates[Date]` Month on the Axis and create two measures to put in the Values section:

```
OpenCount  = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table1, Table1[OPEN_DT] IN DATESMTD(Dates[Date])))
CloseCount = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table1, Table1[CLOSE_DTTM] IN DATESMTD(Dates[Date])))
```

Then your chart should look like this:

[image: Stacked Bar Chart 1]

---

Another option is to unpivot your two columns in the query editor:

[image: Unpivotted Data]

Put the new `Date` column Month on the Axis, the new `Type` column as the Legend, and count of `Date` or count of `Type` in the Values section. This should give a similar chart.

[image: Stacked Bar Chart 2]