# Comparison of incoming and completed orders in Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi

I have a table with a list of orders that among other things includes a unique order number, a date the order was sent in for financing, and a later date that the financing was approved. A portion of the table might look something like this:

```
Order ID | Date sent to finance | Date completed by finance team
123      | 1/1/2016             | 3/1/2016
124      | 5/5/2017             | 8/6/2017
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to produce any kind of visual that compares a count of how many orders were sent to finance in a specific time frame (like, say, September 2017) and how many orders had their financing approved in that same time frame. For example there might have been 10 total orders that were approved by finance in September 2017 and 20 total orders that came into finance during September 2017 even if they're not the same orders. My goal is to compare that 20 with that 10.

An ideal visualization would have months and years for one axis, count of orders for the other axis, and something like two line charts displaying the two different counts.

I'm not even sure how to start going about this. Could anyone set me on the right path?

Comment: This looks pretty similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52118138/power-bi-show-data-per-month) I answered earlier. You just need a line chart instead of a bar chart.

Comment: The creation of the Dates table seems to have worked (it's a table consisting of every date since 1/1/1900, it looks like) but the two measures don't appear to be returning any values, either in a chart or as a matrix. I tried creating the measures separately against both the Table1 and the Dates tables in case that made any difference but neither returned results.